# Is low-rank factorization another name for low-rank approximation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, matrix-decomposition

I need to learn low-rank factorization and its application in machine learning and digital image processing. But I have two questions:

1. Is low-rank factorization another name for low-rank approximation? If the answer is no, what is the main difference between them?
2. Would you please introduce me several references from which I can learn low-rank factorization?

Comment: Could mean alot but Bananach seems to have a good summary. For tensors the rank is the least integer for the number of terms of rank-1 outer products required to sum up the tensor. For tensors this decomposition is unique, but omitting the "least number of terms" requirement often makes it non-unique.

Comment: @mathreadler Can you introduce a book?

Comment: Try first and get a really good in depth knowledge in Linear Algebra.

Comment: @mathreadler  
I'm currently reading "linear algebra and its application" by David c.lay. I will finish it in next few days. where can I learn Low-factorization from it?
where did you learn Low-rank factorization?

Comment: A good start is to learn singular value decomposition (SVD), principal component analysis (PCA), eigenvalue decompositions. Seems chapter 7 has some examples with PCA to digital image processing. PCA can give the least-error in the variance sense rank-1 approximation of a matrix, and matrices are 2-tensors. But first try and focus on learning the intro courses as well as you can, probability, linalg, calculus will all be essential in understanding both machine learning and digital image processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say low-rank factorization is a special case of low-rank approximation.

Low-rank approximation considers approximation of vectors in tensor-product vector spaces by means of sums of elementary tensors, with the goal to have as short as possible sums while having as good an approximation as possible.

Low-rank factorization is the special case where the tensor product is the outer product of vectors (defined by $(a\otimes b)_{ij}:=a_ib_j$ for vectors $a$ and $b$). Note for example, that Truncated Singular Value Decompositions of a matrix $M$ consists in truncating the sum in $M=U\Sigma V=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sigma_j u_j\otimes v_j$. By omitting those terms with small $\sigma $, you introduce the least error (when measured in appropriate norms)

Summary: The central observation was that multiplication of matrices shaped $(m,n)$ and $(n,k)$ can be viewed 'componentwise' by writing it as sum of $n$ multiplications of rows of length $m$ with columns of length $k$ and that this allows you to think of matrix multiplication as summing up elementary tensors

Comment: What references do you suggest for learning this topic?

Comment: I'm currently reading "linear algebra and its application" by David c.lay. I just have finished chapter four. According to what I have read and index of the book there is no matrix low rank factorization in it. Can you introduce a book?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am not working on this topic